# Are there any molecules with the same spectrum?

Tags: spectroscopy

Are there any two distinct types of atom or molecule that have identical emission or absorption spectra?

Comment: R/S chiral molecules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the R/S chiral molecules mentioned by @user26143. There are also molecules with a distinct atomic composition that have experimentally indistinguishable spectra, even though theoretically there will be minor differences. One example, according to [Rabitz et al. 2009 PRL](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.102.253001) (freely available for viewing) are [flavin mononucleotide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavin_mononucleotide) and [riboflavine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riboflavin) and in fact many other flavins. Due to there very similar structure you need unconventional techniques to be able to distinguish them.